# how to configure full text search in spring boot Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, hibernate-ogm

I am using spring boot 4.2.x But I found a code to modify the configuration from to work with spring boot configartion class.

I did manage to get the search working by changing the config of the neo4j [like here](https://dzone.com/articles/full-text-indexing-fts-neo4j) . But I am trying to do the same from my application where the database is not embedded .
unlike [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7556).

Can I change remote database configuration from client application ?

I am using [this version of neo4j and spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference:configuration:method:java)

Comment: Can you give us an example of the kind of change you want to apply to the remote database?

Comment: I want to upade the list of indexes via java configuration